# Problema na instalação do Phonegap

Tags: android, node.js, mobile, apache-cordova, app

Estou fora de casa e preciso manter meus projetos em dia, comprei um notebook bem simples para minha viagem, sendo que na instalação do PhoneGap esta dando um erro incomum na minha opinião pois nunca tinha visto, espero que possam me ajudar.

[image: Imagem do error]

OBS: **Já tenho instalado: NodeJS e o Git.**

Comment: Provavelmente você não definiu o Git lá nas variaveis globais do sistema, por isso ele não encontra o Git na sua máquina.

Comment: Você precisa instalar o GIT globalmente através de `npm install -g git`, se mesmo assim haver problemas instale através deste pacote: http://git-scm.com/downloads

Answer (score 1):

Tenha a certeza de ter o Git definida na PATH do windows...

- Clique com o botão direito em Meu Computador
- Clique em Configurações avançadas do sistema
- Clique em Variáveis ​​de ambiente na parte inferior da janela
- Em seguida adicione o caminho do git ao final de sua Path de ambiente

> ;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd